# ElasticSearch on docker - 2nd instance kills the first instance

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I'm trying to run multiple versions of ElasticSearch at the same time, should be easy.  Here are my commands:

```
docker run -d --rm -p 9250:9200 -p 9350:9300 --name es_5_3_3_integration -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.3.3
docker run -d --rm -p 9251:9200 -p 9351:9300 --name es_5_4_3_integration -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.3
```

The first docker starts up great.  The 2nd docker starts, but at the cost of killing the first docker.  If I run it without the `-d` I don't get any info back to the UI about why the docker stopped.

Comment: How much RAM did you give to docker? ES 5 starts with 2GB of heap by default (see jvm.options) so if your Docker doesn't have at least 4GB the first instance gets killed indeed.

Comment: I did not specify anything custom.

Comment: That's probably it.  How can I tell the docker to use only, say, 500M of memory?

Comment: You should probably start ES with less heap than 2GB per server, I'd say.

Comment: you were right @Val, adding -e ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms200m -Xmx200m" fixed it.  Want to write up an answer and I'll give you the points?  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, ES on docker tries to take 2G of memory.  So 2 dockers was trying to take up 4G of memory, which my machine didn't have.

The solution: limit the amount of memory each ES instance tried to take to 200mb using the following switch `-e ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms200m -Xmx200m"`

Full, working commands for 4 concurrent dockers:

```
docker run -d --rm -p 9250:9200 -p 9350:9300 --name es_5_3_3_integration -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" -e ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms200m -Xmx200m" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.3.3
docker run -d --rm -p 9251:9200 -p 9351:9300 --name es_5_4_3_integration -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" -e ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms200m -Xmx200m" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.3
docker run -d --rm -p 9252:9200 -p 9352:9300 --name es_5_5_3_integration -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" -e ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms200m -Xmx200m" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.3
docker run -d --rm -p 9253:9200 -p 9353:9300 --name es_5_6_4_integration -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" -e ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms200m -Xmx200m" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.4
```

Thank you to @Val who really answered this question in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a lack of memory problem, you can check if your container was *OOMKilled* ([OOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory)).

First check if the exit code of the container is 137 = (128+9) Container received a SIGKILL.
You can test it with `docker ps -a` or

```
docker inspect --format='{{.State.ExitCode}}' $INSTANCE_ID
```

Then you can check the state of the container with :

```
docker inspect --format='{{.State.OOMKilled}}' $INSTANCE_ID
```

If it returns true, it was a OOM problem.

Further details at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user-memory-constraints .
Extract :

> By default, kernel kills processes in a container if an out-of-memory
>   (OOM) error occurs. To change this behaviour, use the
>   --oom-kill-disable option. Only disable the OOM killer on containers where you have also set the -m/--memory option. If the -m flag is not
>   set, this can result in the host running out of memory and require
>   killing the host’s system processes to free memory.