# Conflict between two Docker containers of different Elasticseach images

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I am using two different Docker images of Elasticsearch on two different projects:

- Project 1: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.6
- Project 2: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.8

It works, but I have noted a weird behaviour, when I start the one with the 6.8.6 version the other crashes:

```
f35d8b319ec0 docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.8   "/bin/bash bin/es-do…"   3 hours ago          Exited (137) Less than a second ago
```

If doing a `docker-compose up`, Docker tries to restart it but without success (same message).

Now If I do a `composer down` on the other project, then the container with the 5.6.8 version can work again:

```
f35d8b319ec0 docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.8   "/bin/bash bin/es-do…"   3 hours ago         Up 12 seconds (healthy)   9300/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9203->9200/tcp
```

Of course, these two containers forward the Elasticsearch to two different ports 9203 and 9209.

I found something suspicious while writing this question; both containers use the same transport port:

```
9300/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9209->9200/tcp
9300/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9203->9200/tcp
```

Could the problem come from this setting? And how to fix this?

Comment: Those two containers are forwarding same ports are different ports ? and please check the there are using same volume or they are using same name ?

Comment: Hi, 9209 and 9203 they are different. There is no volume. The container names are different I put a prefix "project1-elasticsearch".

Comment: But you are streaming same TCP ports, so you have to change the tcp port binding also, this will be solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, that could come from this. I tried to modify the `transport.port` setting, but it doesn't change the port.

Comment: Why you are chanting the configuration, don't change the configuration  of elastic search just  " docker run -d --name elasticsearch --net somenetwork -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" elasticsearch:tag"

Comment: change that to -p 9201:9200 -p 9301:9300 for one container and -p 9202:9200 -p 9302:9300 for second container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the binding the tcp ports to dockers

```
docker run -d --name elasticsearch1 --net somenetwork -p 9201:9200 -p 9301:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" elasticsearch:tag

docker run -d --name elasticsearch2 --net somenetwork -p 9202:9200 -p 9302:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" elasticsearch:tag
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this same question, and @Sai Kumar's accepted answer was not working for me initially. I finally stumbled across [ElasticSearch on docker - 2nd instance kills the first instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47540547/elasticsearch-on-docker-2nd-instance-kills-the-first-instance) which prompted me to override memory defaults, preventing the respective elasticsearch instances from each gobbling up 2GB of RAM by default.

Full sequence that worked for me:

```
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2

docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.4.1

docker run -d --restart=always --name elasticsearch1 -p 9201:9200 -p 9301:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" -e ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms200m -Xmx200m" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2

docker run -d --restart=always --name elasticsearch2 -p 9202:9200 -p 9302:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" -e ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms200m -Xmx200m" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.4.1
```

I'm now able to verify both containers running at http://localhost:9201/ and http://localhost:9202/ respectively.

EDIT: I was able to achieve the same result by simply going into Docker desktop's Settings > Resources area and upping the Memory (in my case from 2G to 4G).

So evidently the same symptom originally posted by @Coil above (that of endless crash-restart ping-pong between two elasticsearch container instances) can also be the result of memory settings, rather than port mappings or other settings in your `docker run` command.

Comment: It solved the problem for me